# React virtualized List scrollTo by id or other attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

Is there a way to scrollTo an element by ID or any other attribute except index?

I have really long lists (inside accordions) and I have the id of the highlighted div and would like to scroll to it. Problem is I could use doc.getElemById but the element isnt in the dom :(

Answer (score 0):

No. react-virtualized doesn't know anything about the data in a cell. (This enables it to work with arrays, immutable objects, etc.) You'll need to manage your own map of id-to-index somehow.

Comment: :( ok. Do you have any suggestions on how I might be able to achieve it?

Comment: How you could manage an id-to-index map? Not without knowing your data or your application, no.

Comment: No worries @brianvaughn just figured it out... BTW I have to say a BIG THANK YOU for an amazing component and being super responsiveness :) #respect #takeABow

Comment: @prgrmr could you please share your solution? Thks in advance

Comment: Hey @CarlosMendes the thing is I added a data-index attribute to store the index. Doing that when the list gets generated. That ways whenever you want to target an element by id you just look up the index and pass it to react virtualized